# Trigger scanning on a Zebra TC25 with an Android Delphi application

Tags: android, delphi, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm developing an Android application with Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.2 to deploy on a Zebra TC25.
I'm trying to activate the scanner by clicking a button on a screen. (Like pressing the yellow buttons on the sides of the pad)

```
procedure TMainForm.btnScanClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Intent: JIntent; //Declares the intent object
begin
  try
    Intent := TJIntent.Create;
    Intent.setType(StringToJString('text/pas'));
    Intent.setAction(StringToJString('com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION')); 
    Intent.putExtra(StringToJString('com.symbol.datawedge.api.SOFT_SCAN_TRIGGER'), StringtoJString('START_SCANNING'));
    if MainActivity.getPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(Intent, TJPackageManager.JavaClass.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size > 0 then
      MainActivity.startActivity(Intent) //Calls startActivity() to send the intent to the system.
    else
      mmLogs.Lines.Add('Erreur: '+DateTimeToStr(now)+' - Receiver not found');
  except
    on E:Exception do
      mmLogs.Lines.Add('Erreur: '+DateTimeToStr(now)+' - btnScanClick - '+E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Here is the content of the AndroidManifest for the Activity part.

```
<activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
        android:label="%activityLabel%"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
        android:value="%libNameValue%" />
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter> 
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.wa.ZebraDW.ACTION" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter> 
</activity>
```

I took inspiration from that:

- https://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/6-6/guide/output/intent/#singledecodemode
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/FMX.Android_Intents_Sample

I always get the error message about "Receiver not found" in the memo. The device doesn't start scanning.

Comment: When you say "nothing happens", do you mean that the device does not start scanning? Also presumably your error message does not appear in the memo?

Comment: Nothing is happening because you need to send the Intent as a Broadcast Intent but your application is calling startActivity() with the Intent.  Is there a MainActivity.sendBroadcast(Intent)?

Comment: Yes, the device doesn't start scanning. The error messages appear in the memo.

Comment: Yes there is MainActivity.sendBroadcast(Intent).
I tried to replace startActivity by this but currently the problem is just before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine with Delphi 10.3 and the Zebra TC56/TC55 devices tested.
The AndroidManifest remains untouched without any aditional entry needed.

```
procedure TForm1.btnTriggerScanClick(Sender: TObject);
var Intent: JIntent;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init;
  Intent.setAction(StringToJString('com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION_SOFTSCANTRIGGER'));
  Intent.putExtra(StringToJString('com.symbol.datawedge.api.EXTRA_PARAMETER'), StringToJString('START_SCANNING'));
  TAndroidHelper.Activity.sendBroadcast(Intent);
end;
```